# How to compare each row of a data frame to each row of another dataframe and calculate overlap

Tags: r, for-loop, overlap

I have two dataframes with start and end time. I want to compare each row of df2 to each row of df1 and calculate the overlap.

```
df1
    #    start    end
    #1    5       15
    #2    20      28      
    #3    46      68     
    #4    80      87

df2
    #    start    end
    #1    20      40
    #2    65      85
```

So the results should be a vector with results

```
overlaping_duration_1= 8 (overlap from df2 row 1 with df1 row 1)
overlaping_duration_2= 3+5 = overlap from df2 row 2 with df1 row 3 + overlap from df2 row 2 with df1 row 4
```

I tried it with an ifelse approach and cover the different conditions. This is only for the first row for df2.

```
overlap =  ifelse ( df2$start <= df1$start & df1$start <= df2$end & df2$end <= df1$end, df2$end-df1$start, 0)

overlap2 =  ifelse ( df2$start <= df1$start & df1$end <= df2$end, df1$end-df1$start, 0)

overlap3 =  ifelse ( df1$start < df2$start & df2$end <= df1$end, df2$end-df2$start, 0)

overlap4 =  ifelse ( df1$start < df2$start & df2$start <= df1$end & df1$end <= df2$end, df1$end-df2$start, 0)
```

Afterwards the different overlap vectors can be merged. This could be applied over a `for` loop over df2.
This approach is quite cumbersome. Is there a more comfortable way?

Comment: What is the result with the data you've provided?

Comment: The approach is for the first row of df2. I added this info. Therefore, the for loop afterwards. The result is 8, as wished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
df1 = data.table(start=c(5,20,46,80),end=c(15,28,68,87))
df2 = data.table(start=c(20,65), end=c(40,85))

# add row identifer (`rn`) and dummy var (`id`) for cartesian join
df1[,`:=`(id=1, rn=.I)]
df2[,`:=`(id=1, rn=.I)]

# do full join
df = df1[df2,on="id", allow.cartesian=T]

# estimate overlap, by row
result = df[,overlap:=.(min(i.end,end)-max(i.start,start)), by=1:nrow(df)]

# retain positive overlaps, and sum by df2 row number
result[overlap>0, .(total = sum(overlap)), by = .(rn=i.rn)]
```

Output:

```
   rn total
1:  1     8
2:  2     8
```

Update: You can also avoid the full join, by instead keying `df2` on `start` and `end` and using `data.table::foverlaps`:

```
library(data.table)
df1 = data.table(start=c(5,20,46,80),end=c(15,28,68,87))
df2 = data.table(start=c(20,65), end=c(40,85))
setkey(df2,start,end)
df = foverlaps(df1,df2[,rn:=.I], nomatch=NULL)
df[,overlap:=.(min(i.end,end)-max(i.start,start)), by=1:nrow(df)][, .(total =sum(overlap,na.rm=T)),by=rn]
```

Output:

```
   rn total
1:  1     8
2:  2     8
```